# sql calculate multiple records with another table

Tags: database, oracle, relational-database, calculated-columns

I have two tables here. What I want is calculate(add) the amount and balance within these two table. But the difficult is that the two account_no are the same(A-102) in transactions table. So how to add `amount` to `balance` when `transactions.account_id`= `account.account_no = A-102`??

[image: This is transactions table]

[image: The account table]

What I have done is :

```
    select account_no, balance + (
                              select t.amount
                              from transactions t
                              where t.account_no = 'A-222')
    from b_account 

    where account_no = 'A-222';
```

This method works only A-305 and A-222.
If I write like this, it won't work..

```
select account_no, balance + (
                              select t.amount
                              from transactions t
                              where t.account_no = (
                                                    select t.account_no 
                                                    from b_account ba, transactions t
                                                    where ba.account_no = t.account_no
                                                    )      
                              )
from b_account 
where account_no = (select t.account_no 
                    from b_account ba, transactions t
                    where ba.account_no = t.account_no);
```

Any help thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group` by account number and `sum` all amounts and then join the result to the account table. Try this

```
with cte as
(
 select account_no, SUM(t.amount) amount
 from transactions t
 --where t.account_no = 'A-222'
 group by account_no
)

Select a.account_no, balance + coalesce(b.amount,0) new_balance
from b_account a
left outer join cte b on a.account_no = b.account_no
--where a.account_no = 'A-222'
```

Comment: Wow, it definitely can work. So much appreciate for it..But it just output `A-102`, `A-222`, `A-305` these three `account_no`, what if I also want other records from the `account` table? @rs.

Comment: @Sunny, check my updated answer, change inner join to left outer join and make sure to check if amount is null when you add balance to amount

Comment: Yh, it totally work well..Thank you a lotttt..I have to do some research on it. It's a new thing for me. lol @rs.